# lightning-input-rich-text QuillJS

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I see in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation) it says this component is based on QuillJS. Does this mean somehow we have access to the Quill API somehow? It also mentions that 'custom-buttons' are 'Reserved for internal use. Custom buttons to add to the toolbar'. So this means that we as developers cannot use custom buttons then and can only use what they provide to us right?

I have also attempted to load in Quill as a static resource and build out my own text editor, but was not having luck with that. Has anyone tried to create custom buttons or create their own rich text editor in LWC? Any advice or pointing in a direction would be greatly appreciated and very helpful!

Comment: Have you found any solution to that ?

Comment: @Hugo sorry I just saw this I have been away. I have not. I am guessing you are searching too...any luck?

Comment: No luck ahah sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Quill API through the custom-buttons attribute, but for most use cases like creating custom buttons you're better off with the 'Rich Text Toolbar Button' component (still in beta while writing this, but it works fine for me).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-rich-text-toolbar-button/documentation